# notepad++ keyword only if at beginning of line

Tags: regex, notepad++, keyword

Is there a way to create a rule for a Keyword in your User Define Language that states that in order for this to be a keyword, it must be at the beginning of the line ... or at least be the first word on the line?

Comment: this question has already been answered on Super User

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/881614/notepad-user-defined-language-regex/881628#881628

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: I'm the guy who answered the question on SuperUser. The same answer:*

I am afraid this is not possible. You can consult [UDL2 documentation](http://udl20.weebly.com/index.html) to learn about User Defined Language capabilities. It is intentionally restricted in order to be easy enough giving a compromise between usability for ordinary users and efficiency.

**Solution:** The only thing I can advise to you beyond UDL2 is to create your own build of Notepad++. If you get the source, you can see that all built-in language highlighters are implemented procedurally using `.lex` files. You can create yours and there you have unlimited highlighting possibilities. Then you need to add color definitions to existing XML files, menu item and necessary bindings and you should be done. Hint: built-in **Batch** language is already highlighting first word on the line so maybe it is a good point to start from.

**Workaround:** if highlighting of first word on line is sufficient to you, just switch langugage to **Batch**. :)

**Another solution:** In these cases, user RProgram always suggests people to switch from Notepad++ to [SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/) editor. Its user-defined languages have much wider capabilities. Maybe this will be the fastest way how you can get to desired result without going too deep.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the built-in 'INI File' language option already highlights the first words ('Keys') up to the '=' sign (besides coloring 'section' names) but that's all. It may be useful for some uses but is certainly limited in applicability.